# Is it possible to call notifyAll() on threads waiting on a specific lock in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am curious if there is a way to notify threads that are waiting on a specific lock. I am getting exception and as I understand this is because I call notifyAll() inside the synchronized piece of code in different methods.
As I understand notifyAll() is waking up ALL threads that are waiting on all locks. Here is a code

```
public class Buffer {

    private static Buffer instance = null;
    private boolean full = false;
    private boolean empty = true;

    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    private char[] arr;
    private int i;

    private Buffer(){
        arr = new char[26];
        i = 0;
    }

    public static synchronized Buffer getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Buffer();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void put(char c){

        synchronized(lock1){
            while(full){
                try{
                    wait();
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }

            arr[i++] = c;
            empty = false;
            if(i == 25){
                full = true;
                notifyAll();
            }else{
                full = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public char get(){
        synchronized(lock2){
            while(empty){
                try{
                    wait();
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }

            if(--i == 0){
                empty = true;
            }else{
                notifyAll();
            }
            full = false;
            return arr[i];
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return i == 0;
    }
}
```

Exception I get

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at Producer_consumer.Buffer.get(Buffer.java:58)
    at Producer_consumer.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:14)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Or if it is not possible.. how such situations are resolved?

Comment: Waiting with a lock held is something you should try hard not to do.  A producer-consumer queue with callbacks can help.  In other words, wait-and-notify idioms are like concurrent assembly language.  You should be using the high-level concurrency API's in java.util.concurrent instead.

Comment: @scottb You do realize that [`wait` releases the lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()), right? Only the lock that you call `wait` on of course, and you must hold it, otherwise it throws an `IllegalMonitortateException`.

Comment: You must wait and notify on the respective locks. One for the full and one for the empty case (and get wakes up the full case and put wakes up the empty case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifyAll` wakes up all threads that are waiting on a specific lock (the one that you are calling `notifyAll` on. But to call `wait` or `notify`/`notifyAll` you need to hold the synchronized lock on *that* monitor.

If you don't hold a synchronized lock on the monitor when you call `wait` or `notify`, then you get the `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

So when in your example, you are within `synchronized(lock1){...}`, you need to call `lock1.wait()` and `lock1.notifyAll()`, and similarly on `lock2`.

What you are doing now in your code is to call `wait` on `this` object. Every object in Java has a monitor, and you can synchronize, wait and notify on it. So you need to be very careful on which object you perform these actions.

If you want to notify a different monitor, you need to synchronize on it first.

Comment: I added as you said.. but now Consumer threads do not work, like I do not get any exceptions but also my Consumer threads do not do anything...

Comment: You may be notifying the wrong monitor. Reading through your code, you probably are. You probably want to notify lock2 in your put method, and lock1 in your get method. In order to do that, you need to synchronize on it: `synchronized (lock2) { lock2.notifyAll(); }` in your put method and likewise for lock1 in the get method.

Comment: Well.. I did as you said...
synchronized (lock1) { lock1.wait(); lock1.notifyAll(); } for put
and likewise for lock2 for get...

does not work for consumers...

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious if there is a way to notify threads that are waiting on a specific lock.

Yes.

> As I understand notifyAll() is waking up ALL threads that are waiting on all locks.

No. It wakes up all threads that are waiting on the object you call it on.

It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, lock2 is being used by the consumers
and lock1 is being used by the producers.

When the consumer gets the last character from the array , sets
empty to true and full to false who is going to notify the 
producer thread to wake up and start producing again.

So the producer will remain in wait state ....

Answer (score 0):

Another approach towards solving your problem is...change the object
on which you need the lock.
According to your program, my analysis tells me it is the Buffer 
instance that you want to get a lock on.
Reason is it is this instance which contains the character array that
both the producer and consumer acts upon.

So try this construct.....synchronized(instance)